# Callback pattern in Rust

Tags: design-patterns, rust, callback, borrow-checker

Looking to implement a callback interface of two flavors. Immutable (cannot mutate the struct the callback is assigned to) and mutable (can mutate the struct the callback is assigned to).

```
type Callback<'a> = dyn FnMut(&'a MyStruct<'a>);
type CallbackMut<'a> = dyn FnMut(&'a mut MyStruct<'a>);

struct MyStruct<'a> {
    callback: &'a Callback<'a>,
    callback_mut: &'a CallbackMut<'a>
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new(callback: &'a Callback<'a>, callback_mut: &'a CallbackMut<'a>) -> MyStruct<'a> {
        MyStruct {
            callback,
            callback_mut,
        }
    }

    pub fn trigger_callback(&'a self) {
        (self.callback)(self);
    }

    pub fn trigger_callback_mut(&'a mut self) {
        (self.callback_mut)(self);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::minimal::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {

        let mut triggered1 = false;
        let callback = |_my_struct: &MyStruct| {
            triggered1 = true;
        };

        let mut triggered2 = false;
        let callback_mut = |_my_struct: &mut MyStruct| {
            triggered2 = true;
        };

        let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new(&callback, &callback_mut);
        my_struct.trigger_callback();
        my_struct.trigger_callback_mut();
        assert!(triggered1, "Should call immutable callback");
        assert!(triggered2, "Should call mutable callback");
    }
}
```

So I am trying to understand how to make this pattern work in Rust and am confused about how to resolve the following few compiler errors.

1. How do I use the assigned callback and pass the struct into it? What other patterns are available for doing this that are more Rust-friendly?

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.callback_mut` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/minimal.rs:22:9
   |
6  |     callback_mut: &'a CallbackMut<'a>
   |                   ------------------- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `&'a mut CallbackMut<'a>`
...
22 |         (self.callback_mut)(self);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

2. How can I mutate the variable captured in the callback? What other patterns are available for doing this that are more Rust-friendly?

```
error[E0597]: `triggered1` does not live long enough
  --> src/minimal.rs:35:13
   |
34 |         let callback = |_my_struct: &MyStruct| {
   |                        ----------------------- value captured here
35 |             triggered1 = true;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
43 |         let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new(&callback, &callback_mut);
   |                                           --------- cast requires that `triggered1` is borrowed for `'static`
...
48 |     }
   |     - `triggered1` dropped here while still borrowed
```

3. It seems like I should be able to do an operation that is an immutable borrow strictly followed by an operation that is a mutable borrow when the immutable borrow does not live until the mutable borrow.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `my_struct` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/minimal.rs:45:9
   |
44 |         my_struct.trigger_callback();
   |         --------- immutable borrow occurs here
45 |         my_struct.trigger_callback_mut();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^--------------------^^
   |         |         |
   |         |         immutable borrow later used by call
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

4. How would I then reference the variables that were augmented in the callbacks?

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `triggered1` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/minimal.rs:46:17
   |
34 |         let callback = |_my_struct: &MyStruct| {
   |                        ----------------------- borrow of `triggered1` occurs here
35 |             triggered1 = true;
   |             ---------- borrow occurs due to use of `triggered1` in closure
...
43 |         let mut my_struct = MyStruct::new(&callback, &callback_mut);
   |                                           --------- cast requires that `triggered1` is borrowed for `'static`
...
46 |         assert!(triggered1, "Should call immutable callback");
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `triggered1`
```

EDIT: Some additional info.

The desire is to implement hook functionality in a state machine whereby I can call hooks on events - state entry, state exit, edge traversal.

Examples of an immutable callback

```
let mut collected_values = Vec::new();
let immutable_callback_example = |my_struct: &MyStruct| {
    collected_values.push(my_struct.some_val.clone());
};
# run through a bunch of code that might call the trigger_callback an arbitrary number of times
# Do something with the collected values - report out etc
```

```
let mut my_structs = Vec::new();
let immutable_callback_example = |my_struct: &MyStruct| {
# Some event indicates we need to create a new struct
    state_machines.push(MyStruct {
      -10,
      callback,
      callback_mut,
    });
};
# run through a bunch of code that might call the trigger_callback an arbitrary number of times
# Do something with the final collection of structs - report out etc
```

Example of a mutable callback

```
let mut collected_values = Vec::new();
let mutable_callback_example = |my_struct: &mut MyStruct| {
    collected_values.push(my_struct.some_val.clone());
# Wrap this back around to 0
    if my_struct.some_val > 10 {
        my_struct.some_val = 0;
    }
};
# run through a bunch of code that might call the trigger_callback_mut an arbitrary number of times
# Again, report out
```

Comment: Do your callbacks actually need access to the `MyStruct` value? Neither of your tests use them, so it's hard to give suggestions on how to fix some of this. Also why store a reference to the functions instead of the functions themselves?

Comment: The design fundamentally will not work. if those callbacks need to be `FnMut` that means they could modify their capture variables, which means they are mutating themselves. Which means, those fields have to be `callback: &'a mut Callback<'a>`. But then you can never call them  while passing `&self` because you'll have an immutable and mutable borrow at the same time. The functions could actually do bad things if this was allowed.

Comment: For example, since they have access to fields of `&self`, they could call themselves - which would be unsound if they are mutating their captured variables.

Comment: It's really hard to offer a suggestion for how to solve your problem because we don't know what you actually need to achieve. Perhaps it could be solved with channels? I don't know.

Comment: Edited with comments. The desire is for general hook functionality in an event processing system. I think you might be on to something with channels, though I'd rather introduce the complication/optimization of multi-threading at a later point.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am thinking of the case where I have mulitple MyStruct instances all referencing the same callbacks.

Comment: That feels like optimizing for the wrong case to me. Since your callbacks can be mutating their internal state, you'd need synchronization of some kind to reuse the same callback multiple times. You can still always use references if you want, but requiring references adds a lot required of restrictions that get in your way here.

Comment: How about something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2d989e8eee5706ff18d9f812c2da092

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thats awesome! I'll play around with what you have. I was struggling to figure out the annotations necessary to convey my intent, so this is HUGELY helpful

Comment: @loganfsmyth One last item - with the trait constraints on the new() parameters, how would I make a callback optional? my first thought is `Option<impl for<'b> FnMut(&'b MyCallbackData) + 'a>` but that is not functioning as I would expect

Comment: Updated playground with optionals, but not on the new call signature https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fce91967e166054d32a59c0892d88d01

Comment: How about this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ccda926c63037a84cc9f76b2d0c661f9

Answer (score 2):

`FnMut` must be able to mutate itself, so you won't be able to use immutable `&dyn FnMut`. You'd need `&mut dyn FnMut`.

But the big problem is that you're overusing *temporary references*. `&` in Rust is not equivalent to using objects "by reference" in other languages, and its semantics come with quite serious limitations. In 99% of cases it is a mistake to use references inside structs.

To *store* something "by reference" you should be using the `Box` type, e.g. `Box<dyn FnMut()>`. It's a pointer in memory, exactly like `&`, but it's not tried to a single scope, and doesn't "infect" the code with lifetime annotations and borrow-checker limitations.

Similarly, to have some data accessible both inside and outside of the callback function, you're going to need to wrap that data in `Arc` instead of using `&`. For mutable access: `Arc<Mutex>`. For a boolean, `Arc<AtomicBool>` works too.

Closures that capture local variables by reference can't be used outside of the scope of the variable, which usually makes them impossible to use for observers and event-based callback programming patterns.

1. Don't put temporary references in structs.
2. Wrap everything in `Arc`, clone `Arc`s, and use `move ||` closures.

Comment: So really I should be looking to some other mechanism for my event-based callback patterns? Ultimately, I'm trying to tie this into an external function call (ie in python). I looked as channels, but I really want the execution of the callbacks to be synchronous.

Comment: You can use callbacks, but you need to use `Arc<Callback>` (which is same as a reference in Python) instead of `&Callback`, which is semantically invalid for what you're trying to do. You're not running into a limitation of the language, you're using one feature mistaking it for another.

To take args by reference, use `Arc<Mutex<dyn for<'a> FnMut(&'a i32)>>`.